# SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "\":

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is the table where i want to insert the value:

```
" create table if not exists "+CipherCongfigTable +
" ( DATABSE_NAME **TEXT**  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,DATABSE_KEY **TEXT**  NOT NULL);";
```

when i want to insert

```
String **configDBPassword**= "**x\'2DD29CA89\'**"
```

through statement

```
"insert into "+CipherCongfigTable+ " values("+DataBaseName+","+**configDBPassword**+")"
```

I am getting exception:

> unrecognized token: "\":

I need the password in the same format i.e. having escape charecter. Is there any way to do it????

Thanks

Comment: i believe its java creating issue , try \\ instead or use prepared statement

Comment: Why are you using not [insert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) and instead create an SQL injection attack point by *not quoting your parameters properly*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't manually build `INSERT` (or any other if you can avoid it) queries on Android (or any other database wrapper as long as there is a predefined API to get what you want). It opens up your application to quoting problems like the one from your question and --at the worst-- to SQL injection attacks from outside of your application.

For example, setting `configDBPassword = "\"; DROP TABLE <tablename>; --"` I could possibly wreak havoc on your database as long as `configDBPassword` can be entered by the user.

Also, SQLite uses double quotes (`"`), backticks (`` ` ``, borrowed from MySQL), or square brackets (`[]`, borrowed from MS SQL) to quote *identifiers* (e.g. column or table names with spaces in them), *string literals* are canonically quoted with single (`'`) quotes. SQLite is a quite liberal in allowing to mix both quoting types, but it is significantly more readable to use the proper quoting style whereever appropriate. From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

> Programmers are cautioned not to use the two exceptions described in the previous bullets. We emphasize that they exist only so that old and ill-formed SQL statements will run correctly. Future versions of SQLite might raise errors instead of accepting the malformed statements covered by the exceptions above.

As a matter of fact, you should avoid doing the quoting by yourself whenever possible. For inserting values, please instead use [`SQLiteDatabase.insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) which is the proper way of inserting values into an `SQLiteDatabase` on Android. It also does proper quoting of the arguments, too:

```
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("DATABSE_NAME", DataBaseName);
        values.put("DATABSE_KEY", configDBPassword);

        db.insert(CipherCongfigTable, null, values);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

**Always** properly quote your SQL parameters.

Comment: Thanks @dhke  Now i am using SQLiteStatement for building  sql statements and then SQLiteStatement.execute(). I sthis good enough

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
"INSERT INTO "+CipherCongfigTable+ "  values('DataBaseName','configDBPassword')”
```

You are not adding Single quotes(') in your insert query

**Edit :**
If you need to insert string with Single qotes means use like this before insert.

```
configDBPassword = configDBPassword.replace ("'", "''");
```

Also change your **

```
" create table if not exists "+CipherCongfigTable +
" ( DATABSE_NAME TEXT  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,DATABSE_KEY TEXT  NOT NULL);";
```

Comment: Thanks Amsheer . acutlly i need single quotes(') in the password. Is ther any way to do it.???

Comment: Please don't promote incorrect SQL coding techniques. Also, what kind of quotes are those.. and why?

Comment: @user2864740 I edit that from texteditor (mac) so only single quote looks like that now i edited.

Comment: @Amsheer With the quote replacement, your code is now properly preventing SQL injection due to misquoting, but since Android has an actual method to perform insert operations that already handles the quoting, doing the quoting manually seems not the preferred way.